# Django URL // double slash being dropped (Possibly Apache's fault)?

Tags: python, regex, django, apache, url

I have a url with a pattern like so:

```
('^(?i)somewhere/(\d+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$', somewherePage),
```

where it should pick up a URL like:

```
http://foo.com/somewhere/1337/foo/params/that/are//maybe///used/
```

Notice how some of the parameters are not present and result in //. This has stopped working and instead of the correct url I am getting something like:

```
http://foo.com/somewhere/1337/foo/params/that/are/maybe/used/
```

where the needed slashes are not there and my pattern is then not recognized. I think this may be caused by something my apache web server is doing but I am not how to figure this out.

My question is how can I stop the extra slashes from being removed or is there another solution for having a dynamic number of parameters. Also this code used to work fine but has sense stopped. I am unsure what has changed as the code base is legacy but I know this way of passing a variable number of parameters has worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there another solution for having a dynamic number of parameters

Yes, it's called a query string. Instead of that ugly pattern use a simpler one (one that matches required parameters), and pass everything else after `?`, e.g. `example.com/foo/42?p1=foo&p2=bar`.
You can then extract them from `request.GET`.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I am going to doing. Pretty much everything I've found has said it is a terrible idea to place a bunch of /// so I am just going to go ahead and fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I've ran into this question after debugging a similar issue on Django. The extra slash was always dropped due to nginx. Adding a `merge_slashes off` in nginx configuration fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the ugliness of GET parameters, and since this `somewherePage` view implicitly knows to expect a variable number of pieces back from the referring url, you could shift the url-parsing code into the view itself.

That is, make the url pattern like:

```
('^(?i)somewhere/(\d+)/(.*)/$', somewherePage),
```

and split it at the start of your view:

```
def somewherePage(request, somewhere_int, somewhere_pieces):
    import string
    the_pieces = string.split(somewhere_pieces, '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to what was causing the extra // to be removed is some commands from the mod_rewrite Apache module. I have decided to just fix the way I create URLs as suggested by PiotrLegnica.